# How to set planning frame in MoveIt 2

Tags: ros2, moveit, c++, universal-robot

I have a custom MoveIt 2 package for a UR5e robot. While planning and executing the movement, I noticed weird movements where the robot didn't seem to move as expected. I noticed that `getPlanningFrame` returns `world` when I would expect `base_link`. I tried going to different poses and setting the `frame_id` to `base_link`, which seems to work, but the plans are often bizarre.

I am having difficulty finding the issue because I cannot find any variable called `planning_frame` in any of the launch files or associated files. I suspect there is some problem with my `urdf` or `srdf` setup; perhaps changing the `planning_frame` would fix it.

Is there any way to set the planning frame in a MoveIt 2 setup?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue in moveit1 and ros-noetic and I just fixed it. You can use the function `setPoseReferenceFrame (const std::string &pose_reference_frame)` to set a new reference frame to get the pose. My python code:

```
poseframe_id="base"
move_group.set_pose_reference_frame(poseframe_id)
```

Some other information: you can find the default planning_frame in the `<robot>` srdf, it looks like:

```
<group name="ur10e_robot">
  <chain base_link="base_link" tip_link="tool0" />
</group>
```

in the robot description file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly this didn't help in my situation. My `srdf` is set up as you mention, with `chain base_link"base_link" tip_link"tool0"`, but the planning frame is set to `world` nonetheless. As I'm building upon the Universal_Robot_ROS2_Driver, I ended up just planning in the `world` frame instead of trying to build the setup from scratch.